# For which integer values of $k$ can we find one solution to the equation $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=k} \frac{1}{n^s}=0$ by iteration?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function, recurrences

I am trying to find solutions to the well known equation:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=k} \frac{1}{n^s}=0$$

Now with this program below I have found that for certain values of the integer $k$ one can find one of the solutions to partial Riemann zeta function.

```
(*Mathematica 8 start*)Clear[nn, cc, s, x, y];
Print["k can be varied to any integer greater than or equal to 2:"]
k = 16;
cc = 4000;
s = 0;
Do[s = (2 I \[Pi]*(k - 1))/Log[k] + 
   N[Round[Log[1/(-Sum[1/n^s, {n, 1, k - 1}])]/Log[k]*10^120]/10^120, 
    120], {i, 1, cc}]
Print["s"]
s
Print["If the result below is zero, then s is a solution to the \
equation in the question."]
sumx = Sum[1/n^(s), {n, 1, k}]
(*end*)
```

So in the program if you read it I have put $k=16$. What is the pattern in the sequence of different values of $k$? For some values of $k$ it works, for others it does not.

The values:

$$k=4, k=5, k=7, k=8, k=10, k=11, k=16$$

work.

But the values:

$$k=3, k=6, k=9, k=12$$

don't work.

What is the pattern?

Comment: Do values 23 and 48 work as well?

Comment: k=23 works, but k=48 does not work

Comment: I think this question is a copy of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613371/finding-a-solution-to-sum-limits-n-1n-k-frac1ns-0.

Comment: Are you asking if solutions exist for $k=3,6$?

Comment: Not really. I am asking for which integers k the method works. But I was very excited when I wrote this question and totally forgot to consult the Online-Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS), before posting.

Comment: 4+5=9, 9-2=7. 5+7=12, 12-4=8. 7+8=15, 15-5=10. 8+10=18, 18-7=11. 10+11=21, 21-5=16. 11+16=27, 27-4=23. 16+23=39, 39-2=37...ect. Would the pattern be 2,4,5,7,5,4,2?

Comment: Could be. But be aware that the iteration method I have given is similar to a root finding algorithm like Newtons root finding algorithm. The crucial parameter is this term: (2 I \[Pi]*(k - 1))/Log[k] which can be replaced with (2 I \[Pi]*(K))/Log[k]. Changing the value of K changes the success of the root finding iteration I gave. But thank you for the effort, anyways.